# Can't write to SC1DRL register on 68HC12 board--what am I missing?

Tags: c, 68hc11

I am trying to write to use the multiple serial interface on the 68HC12 but am can't get it to talk. I think I've isolated the problem to not being able to write to the SC1DRL register (SCI Data Register Low).

The following is from my SCI ISR:

```
else if (HWRegPtr->SCI.sc1sr1.bit.tdre) {
    /* Transmit the next byte in TX_Buffer. */
    if (TX_Buffer.in != TX_Buffer.out || TX_Buffer.full) {
        HWRegPtr->SCI.sc1drl.byte = TX_Buffer.buffer[TX_Buffer.out];
        TX_Buffer.out++;
        if (TX_Buffer.out >= SCI_Buffer_Size) {
            TX_Buffer.out = 0;
        }
        TX_Buffer.full = 0;
    }
    /* Disable the transmit interrupt if the buffer is empty. */
    if (TX_Buffer.in == TX_Buffer.out && !TX_Buffer.full) {
        Disable_SCI_TX();
    }
}
```

TX_Buffer.buffer has the right thing at index TX_Buffer.out when its contents are being written to HWRegPtr->SCI.sc1drl.byte, but my debugger doesn't show a change, and no data is being transmitted over the serial interface.

Anybody know what I'm missing?

edit:

HWRegPtr is defined as:

```
extern HARDWARE_REGISTER *HWRegPtr;
```

HARDWARE_REGISTER is a giant struct with all the registers in it, and is volatile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that SC1DRL is a write-only register (check the official register docs to be sure -- google isn't turning up the right PDF for me).  That means you can't read it back (even with an in-target debugger) to verify your code.

How is HWRegPtr defined?  Does it have `volatile` in the right places to ensure the compiler treats every write through that pointer as something which must happen immediately?

Comment: I tried to put my answer here, but there's too much formatting so I'll just edit my question and add it there. 

Also, you might be right about the write-only thing, but that's something else that confuses me about the documentation. The documentation says that writes to SC1DRL access the eight bits of the write-only SCI transmit data register (TDR). So when you write to SC1DRL you're really writing to the TDR?

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out on my own--you were right, I couldn't see the what was on the register because it was write-only, but my code was in fact writing to it. I couldn't see anything transmitted over the serial line because I wasn't using a null modem cable. x.x